# Can I call a software dialog box a form?

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote this sentence:

> Figure 1 shows a screenshot of the main form of the software.

While in computer we call a dialog box a form (at least in programming), but in the dictionary I didn't find that meaning.

Is the sentence above acceptable?

Comment: For what audience? As a techie myself I have no problem with your sentence however, if you are writing for a general audience then screen may be a better option

Comment: @PerryW You can say teachers of schools

Comment: A "form" has places where information can be entered, such as boxes for text, checkboxes, date-masks, and so on.  Paper forms had this feature, and the term was adapted for use with computer screens.  If a window does not ask the user to supply information, it would not be a "form" in the sense that most English speakers would have in mind when using the word "form". A minimalist "dialog box" sometimes has only a message and an "OK" button. It is not considered a "form" by non-technical users.

Comment: @TRomano It's not for data entry  nor it is a simple message box. It is the main interface of the application where user does some tasks.

Comment: "Main menu" is a possibility,  or  "main *screen*" (as Perry suggested above).  If the user types more than a few letters of text, it's a screen, not a menu.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, it really depends on the intended audience.

If this sentence formed part of some technical documentation then

> Figure 1 shows a screenshot of the main form of the software.

sounds a little awkward but the meaning is clear as both writer and reader share a common understanding of this use of form.

For a general audience however (and I'd include the teachers that the the OP has mentioned in reply into this group) 'form' would be confusing and ambiguous - it could suggest, for example, that the software is available in a different form to that which is shown in the screenshot.

It's difficult to make a firm recommendation without seeing the image in question but most people would have no problem with actually using 'dialog box'. 'Screen' may well be the best generic term with 'Interface', while technically wrong, being another option that most readers would understand.

Comment: As a technical writer in IT, I would discourage mentioning "interface" in user-facing documentation. Those of us behind the scenes think of it as a UI or a GUI, but these mean nothing to naïve users. To them it's a screen or a window. I wouldn't even mention "dialog box" to a user; I usually call them "pop-ups" if they are modal and are smaller than the screen that evokes them.